# What code is throwing the Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am also new to Java and Android Development, been making a simple game on my Wildfire S for a while and things have been going well except whenever I get a Null Pointer Exception I cannot seem to find what exactly is causing it.

All forums I have searched on, detail what a Null Pointer Exception is or how to pre-emptively overcome them but that is not what I need.

The problem I face here is that the part of code that Eclipse seems to be drawing my attention to seems completely fine and I haven't been editing it at all.  So I have possibly changed something by mistake somewhere.  Not knowing which area has been edited I cannot seem to find out why the error is being thrown.

The log seems to tell me that the error is occuring at the onCreate method in GoalieMenu.java which hasn't been edited in a very long time.  It is simply an Activity which uses mainmenu.xml as its layout, which contains three buttons (start, howToPlay and Exit) each button has XMLs of their own they all seem fine...

I fear this is going to be a really dumb and obvious thing but I'm not greatly familiar with what I am looking at so it is taking me ages and I cannot find it!! grr

here is the log:

```
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable 
to  start activity     
ComponentInfo{com.luk.games.Goalie/com.luk.games.Goalie.GoalieMenu}:
java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831): Caused by: 
java.lang.NullPointerException

04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
com.luk.games.Goalie.GoalieMenu.onCreate(GoalieMenu.java:34)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
04-04 16:27:57.277: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2831):     ... 11 more
```

Here is the GoalieMenu.java:

```
package com.luk.games.Goalie;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GoalieMenu extends Activity {

private Button startGameButton;
private Button howToPlayButton;
private Button exitButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

      this.startGameButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.startGameButton);
      this.startGameButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          startActivity(new Intent("com.luk.games.Goalie.GameActivity"));       
          }
      });

       this.howToPlayButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.howToPlayButton);
       this.howToPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
              startActivity(new Intent("com.luk.games.Goalie.HowToPlayActivity"));              
            }
        });

       this.exitButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.exitButton);
       this.exitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               finish();
           }
       });
}
}
```

mainmenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainmenuscreen"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/startGameButton"
    android:background="@layout/startgamebutton"
    android:layout_height="50dp" 
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dip"/>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/howToPlayButton"
    android:background="@layout/howtoplaybutton"
    android:layout_height="50dp" 
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/exitButton"
    android:background="@layout/exitbutton"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your mainmenu.xml as well.

Comment: There we go, posted it for everyone to see  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GoalieMenu.java:34, I think it is this this `howToPlayButton.setOnClickListener`

howToPlayButton might be null.

Debug and use `try` and `catch` where you suspect.

Comment: i did this:  if (howToPlayButton != null) {
    this.howToPlayButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.howToPlayButton);
    this.howToPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
      startActivity(new Intent("com.luk.games.Goalie.HowToPlayActivity"));
     }
    });
    }

Comment: whoops!

Anyway, I get the same result only its GoalieMenu.java.43 now, I don't know if that has any significance

Comment: I hate counting lines, update your question with the line in question, please.

Comment: this is the point. I really do not know what piece of code is making it throw

Comment: It's telling you line 34 (well now 43). We can't see your line numbers, but counting the lines seems to indicate that it is `howToPlayButton.setOnClickListener` that is throwing it, which suggests that `howToPlayButton` is null at the time of the call. re: your first comment on this answer, try checking whether it's null *after* setting it to the `findViewById` result

Comment: Ohh I see, part of my issue is that I am just not used to using Eclipse's log to locate error lines.


Am I doing the right thing here: -

howToPlayButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.howToPlayButton);
    if (howToPlayButton != null) {
    howToPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
      startActivity(new Intent("com.luk.games.Goalie.HowToPlayActivity"));
     }
    });
    }

sorry I am not sure how to make it view in code

Comment: Okay, excellent that seems to have worked.. Like you said, AFTER setting it to the result of findViewById I wrapped it in an if (howToPlayButton != null) statement it has gotten rid of the error.

Very strange behavior has now ensued but that is a different story ha, thanks for you help on this! :)

Comment: which leads to my original answer. check your reference. findViewById will ONLY return null if it's referencing something not in the layout xml. (tip: check if you're using different layout folders. maybe you forgot to id something in layout_land)

Answer (score 0):

Try start a new activity as follows:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
        GameActivity.class));
```

The same for `HowToPlayActivity`

Comment: I replaced my startActivity line with yours and it throw the same

Comment: My last solution: remove all `this` keyword.

Comment: no that didn't seem to do anything either.  Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that there's someting wrong with one of your `findViewById` statements - check if the element being referenced by R.id. actually exists in your layout xml.

Comment: in the mainmenu.xml file and the r.java all the references seem to be fine

Answer (score 0):

Minor change in your code and try this::::

```
public class GoalieMenu extends Activity {

private Button startGameButton;
private Button howToPlayButton;
private Button exitButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

      findViewById(R.id.startGameButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          startActivity(new Intent("com.luk.games.Goalie.GameActivity"));       
          }
      });

      findViewById(R.id.howToPlayButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
              startActivity(new Intent("com.luk.games.Goalie.HowToPlayActivity"));              
            }
        });

       findViewById(R.id.exitButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               finish();
           }
       });
}
}
```

Try this....